# Did English ever use "hen" to mean "now?"

Tags: historical-linguistics

English has/had so many of these trios: where/there/here, whereby/thereby/ hereby, whither/thither/hither, whence/thence/hence ... and when/then/NOW? Whatever happened to "hen?" Did that form exist in an earlier stage or dialect?

Comment: _Now_ does stand out [like a sore thumb in the paradigm](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html), doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it did.

[**hen**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hen#Etymology_2):

From Middle English henne, heonne, hinne, from earlier henene, heonenen, henen, from Old English heonan, hionan, heonane, heonone (“hence, from here, away, from how”), from Proto-Germanic *hina, *hinanō (“from here”), from Proto-Indo-European *ḱe-, *ḱey- (“this, here”). Cognate with Dutch heen (“away”), German hin (“hence, from here”), Danish hen (“away, further, on”). See also hence.

(dialectal) Hence.

EDITED TO ADD: To be sure, this answer addresses the "Whatever happened to "hen?" Did that form exist in an earlier stage or dialect?" part of your question. **hen** did not really mean 'now'.

Comment: This word doesn't mean "now", though.

Comment: True, I guess I was answering just the " Whatever happened to "hen?" Did that form exist in an earlier stage or dialect?" part. I'll clarify.

Comment: Another cognate: Modern West Frisian "hinne".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **no**, and, what's more, the **deictic** (IE *ke > *hen*)-related forms that Mark Beadles refers to cannot be **directly** connected with the bound morph *-en* of Modern English *then* because *-en* (just as *-ere*, *-us* - as in *thus*, etc.) **is not deictic** in *then, there, thus*, etc. What **is** deictic in all such complex words is the bound morph *th-*, not the *-en* (*-ere, -us*, etc.) that follow it. And, of course, the reason why *now* does not fit in the pseudoparadigm attempted above and why *-en* can never have meant *now* in English, is that *now* **is deictic**, whereas *-en* **cannot** be.

This impossibility can be explained in a principled way: a word (or phrase) containing **two** deictic elements, be they free or bound forms, would violate a universal principle, i.e., **that variables (say a time variable, as in *th-en*) cannot be *doubly bound***. Hence, no deictic can possibly 'bind' (read 'apply to', if you prefer) a constituent that already contains an internal deictic: once the (time/place, etc.) variable is bound, a second deictic would have no variable to bind, biuniqueness would be violated, and the resulting word/phrase would be necessarily ill-formed.

That is, in short, why *then* can not be analysed as [*t(h) + -(h)en = now*] and why the answer to your question is **No, English could never have used *-hen*, (*-en*, rather), to mean *now***, even if deictic *hen*-related forms did exist in, presumably, all primitive IE languages, as Mark Beadles pointed out.

Comment: Great answer as for the "No" in "Was there a word 'hen' to mean 'now'". But how about some thoughts on "Why is there an apparent gap in the regularity of the paradigm", or, alternatively, "Why is it the above merely an 'attempted pseudoparadigm', not a valid pattern?"

Comment: *a word (or phrase) containing two deictic elements, be they free or bound forms, would violate a universal principle*: maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but how about e.g. *this book here*?

Comment: I don't think the asker meant to call *-en* deictic. Rather, *-en* seems like it could be a time-related ending: *wh-ither* = interrogative + allative, *h-ither* = demonstrative + locative, *th-ither* = demonstrative + locative; so *wh-en* = interrogative + time, *\*h-en* = (potentially) demonstrative + time, *th-en* = demonstrative + time.

Comment: @TKR I should have explained the phrasal cases too: I was referring to two th- DETERMINERS, as in '*the this new book', '*that that book over there', etc. Such Det's bind the variable associated with the NP's 'new book', 'book over there', because they c-command them. In 'This book here', 'That book over there', 'here' or 'there' do NOT bind the NP variable because they do NOT c-command the WHOLE NP, they BELONG to it. In particular, in your example 'this book here', 'here' modifies 'book', but is NOT a Det, cannot bind the variable of 'book here', and no double-binding problem arises.

Comment: Isn't that just part of the general rule that English disallows multiple determiners (with an exception for quantifiers)? In any case if it's a syntactic rule about determiners, I don't see how it would apply to single words.

Comment: @TKR It is NOT just a syntactic rule about determiners. The really 'general' rules are that variables must be biuniquely bound by 'operators' (determiners, wh-elements, quantifiers in the logical sense) and that features, being functions, must have unique values. (Quantifiers like 'many', by the way, are not determiners, and so no exception; note that double Q's are also excluded in NP's). Such principles apply across the board, word-internally, too. Further word-internal consequences are that a V cannot carry two tense affixes, an N cannot be doubly specified for number, gender or case, etc.